# titanium: Adding things to a scrollview

Tags: titanium

So i have this code:

```
var answerView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({ //var added
    top: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight*0.55,
    left:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth*0.1,
width: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth*0.8,
backgroundImage: '/images/labelBackground.png',
borderRadius: 8,
height: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight*0.5,
contentHeight:'auto',
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator:true,
    scrollType:'vertical',
});
for (var j = 0; j < question.answers.length; j++){
    var row = createRow(question.answers[j]);
answerView.add(row);
}
```

and this function:

```
function createRow(answer) {
var row = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:'100%', 
    height: 'auto',
});
var answerButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    top: '1%',
    left: '1%',
    title: answer.answer,
    value: answer.order,
    width:'98%',
    font : {fontSize:'12sp'},
});
row.add(answerButton);
return row;
}
```

The problem is, the darn thing overlays all the buttons into one... that is, it isn't "pushing down" the rows. From the titanium tutorial here:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView

I would have thought this would work, but it doesn't. I know i can do some magic with the numbers and send each row the position it should have, but I thought maybe titanium would be clever enough to do that? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh jesus.

Titanium is moronic in this instance - the problem was I had

height: 'auto' in the definition of each row - that is:

```
function createRow(answer) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:'100%', 
        height: 'auto',
    });
...
```

And funnily enough, that makes each row REALLY BIG, probably as big as the entire space alloted for the row. I don't know, i never tried to scroll through it. So just change the height value for the row to something sane - i always base mine off the display height.

Now I have

```
function createRow(answer) {
    var row = Ti.UI.createView({
        width:'100%', 
        height: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight*0.1,
    });
...
```

and all is well.

Comment: you can just set the `layout:'vertical'` property on the scroll view so when you add children to it they space correctly with no overlap